# Python for loop, iterating over values from numpy arrange method

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, for-loop

I need to write code that tests a numpy array of cutoff values for a classification problem. The values to test are stored in the `cutoff_list` variable. I then want to place the list of resulting confusion matrices in a dictionary. However, the code below gives me only the first dictionary entry (confusion matrix for the first test value):

```
cutoff_list = [np.arange(0,1,0.01)]  # list of test values
dictionary = {}  
for i, v in enumerate(cutoff_list):
    actual = (df.observed)
    predicted = np.where(df.indicator > i, 1, 0)

    df_confusion = confusion_matrix(actual, predicted) / len(df.indicator)   

    dictionary[i] = df_confusion

print(dictionary)
```

Libraries that I am using:

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
```

Is this a problem with the loop or the dictionary update step? I'm new to Python, have more experience with R and still struggling here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop runs only once, because of the way you set it up.

You are enclosing the return of the `np.arrange(0.1.0.01)` in a list which breaks the way you want your for loop to run. You are getting just one value because the for loop runs just once as the outer list has just one item.

```
>>> cutoff_list = [np.arange(0,1,0.01)]
>>> cutoff_list
[array([0.  , 0.01, ... 0.98, 0.99])]
>>> type(cutoff_list)
<class 'list'>
```

You want to get the actual numpy array:

```
>>> cutoff_list = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
>>> cutoff_list
array([0.  , 0.01, ... 0.98, 0.99])
>>> type(cutoff_list)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Change the line `cutoff_list = [np.arange(0,1,0.01)]` to `cutoff_list = np.arange(0,1,0.01)` and see whether that resolves your problem.

I would also imagine that you want to use `v` instead of `i` in this line:

```
    predicted = np.where(df.indicator > i, 1, 0)
```

as the `i` will hold just the enumerating value that you use as key for your dict, whereas the `v` will hold the values from `cutoff_list`.

Comment: thanks, that helps in a sense that now the loops runs through the range but the value of df_confusion remains the same in each iteration (the first value) -- is the dictionary being updated correctly? it seems like this might be a problem here

Comment: That's harder to debug without the values that your code uses but have you updated the line where you define `predicted` as suggested in my answer? If not, change the line to `predicted = np.where(df.indicator > v, 1, 0)` and see what happens.

Comment: never mind! this was me using the wrong column for probabilities -  thanks a lot for your help